# Windows Service solution using .net core 3.1 and IHostBuilder

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, async-await, windows-services

I have a requirement to create a windows service which will read from 'n' (configurable number) of TCP sockets.
I am considering something like this.
Is it appropriate/good design for a windows service to instantiate multiple async processes like this?
I am wanting to use the .net core DI container.  So I can inject services like TcpSockerReaderService in this case but most likely others as well.
Is there a better way to do this?
Will the Cancellation Token get through to the Socket Reader instances if the service is shut down in Windows services or the server is shut down gracefully?
Any advice or comment would be appreciated.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) => 
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
                services.AddScoped<ITcpSocketReaderService, TcpSocketReaderService>();

            }).UseWindowsService();
}


public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;

    public Worker(IServiceProvider services, ILogger<Worker> logger)
    {
        Services = services;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public IServiceProvider Services { get; }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Consume Scoped Service Hosted Service running.");

        int socketCount = 5;  //get from config
        for (var socketID = 1; socketID <= socketCount; socketID++)
        {
            await ProcessSocket(socketID, stoppingToken);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Socket Worker Process Spawned");

        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested) ;
    }

    private async Task ProcessSocket(int socketID, CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"ProcessSocket is reading SocketID {socketID}.");

        IServiceScope serviceScope = Services.CreateScope();
        using var scope = serviceScope;
        var socketReaderService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ITcpSocketReaderService>();

        //socketID will be mapped to TCP End Point
        await socketReaderService.ReadSocket(socketID, stoppingToken);
    }


    public override async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Worker Service is stopping.");

        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your concrete question here? Is something not working? I think if you ask "is this a good software design/architecture?" - then I would say: "maybe" - depends on your needs / requirements. It is fine to use DI it is also fine to use it in a ```Worker``` (```IHostedService```). All depends on what you need or what you have implemented in your ```ITcpSocketReaderService```

Comment: My testing of it is working.  I want the best most performant solution.
My concrete questions are:
Can you think of a problem (or a better way) with the code that gets the sockerReaderService from DI container.
    IServiceScope serviceScope = Services.CreateScope();
    using var scope = serviceScope;
    var socketReaderService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ITcpSocketReaderService>();
That code will be called every loop.
This will instatiate a new socketReaderService on every loop right?
Is this OK or would it be better as a singleton and call static methods.

Comment: Also. What does scoped actually mean?
What does Services.CreateScope(); actually do?
N.B. The sockerReaderService() is going to read a TCP socket as name implies and as explained in the intro.
It will read a small amount of data and raise an event to pass it to another service to process.
It will do this for it's lifetime until the server is shut down.

Comment: [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1) ```.CreateScope()``` means all services (transient and scoped) which are resolved via ```scope.ServiceProvider...``` are newly created service instances. Singletons stay singletons :) ... In your code this means your ```ITcpSocketReaderService``` is instanciated each time you execute ```ProcessSocket```. So maybe it is better to wrap the ```using(scope)``` block around your ```foreach(ProcessSocket)``` block to reuse this instance.

Comment: I think that is what I want though.  I want the ProcessSocket method to become an independent thread/Process isolated from the other instances.  Each will process a socket at a different IP but in parallel.  They should not know about each other.  A normal loop can't work.  Process flow will never come back to the loop.  Each loops processing (a ProcessSocket method call) will process data until the server is shut down

Comment: @davidbtosh - You deleted the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65162560/parse-c-sharp-text-file when we could have still helped you. There are many many many parsers out there for C#. Simply doing https://www.google.com.au/search?q=C%23%20parser gives you loads of results.